# jQuery autocomplete turn off

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

### 1st question

I have a dropdownlist, filled with countries (from xml file).

When you choose a country, you can use the autocomplete for a textbox.
This autocomplete has postal codes from the choosen country.

Now I want to set the autocomplete off right after the dropdownlist.change event
for preventing that the autocomplete (filled with postal codes) for 1 country also work for another country. But how do you turn it off?

Code:

```
//when changing country, other postcodes will load
        $('[id$=landenDropDown]').change(function () {

            //autocompletes removal
            ...

            $('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').html("");

            var LandCode = $('[id$=landenDropDown]').attr("value");

            //autocomplete with postal codes for Belgium
            if (LandCode == "BE") {
                //autocomplete postcode from selected country
                $('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').autocomplete("PostcodeBE.aspx");

            }
             //autocomplete with postal codes for Holland
            else if (LandCode == "NL") {
                //autocomplete postcode from selected country
                $('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').autocomplete("thingXml.aspx");

            }

            else {
                //test
                getal += 1;
                alert(getal);
            }
```

The problem is when the autocomplete is finished and select an other country
that this autocomplete still exist, even when it doesnt have to show up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please view the documentation: [(Doc)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ disabled: true });
```

If this solution doesnt work for you, you might have somewhere other problems.
Make your code a little better, maybe something is causing some internal errors

change

```
$('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').html("");
```

to

```
$('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').val("");
```

try to work like this for postcodetextbox:

```
$('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').autocomplete({
      source: "somesource.aspx",
      change: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).autocomplete("destroy");
      }
});
```

But this will disable the user from using it again...

You could also disable the textbox.

```
$('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: it seems that this doesnt want to work, i also tried several other thing like remove, destroy, .. but nothing works for me at the moment

Answer (score 1):

```
    //when changing country, other postcodes will load
    $('[id$=landenDropDown]').bind($.browser.msie ? 'propertychange' : 'change', function () {

        //autocompletes removal
        ...

        var LandCode = $('[id$=landenDropDown]').attr("value");

        $('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').autocomplete('destroy');

        //autocomplete with postal codes for Belgium
        if (LandCode == "BE") {
            //autocomplete postcode from selected country
            $('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').autocomplete("PostcodeBE.aspx");

        }
         //autocomplete with postal codes for Holland
        else if (LandCode == "NL") {
            //autocomplete postcode from selected country
            $('[id$=POSTCODETextBox]').autocomplete("thingXml.aspx");

        }

        else {
            //test
            getal += 1;
            alert(getal);
        }
```